# Python: Referencing global variables inside a function

Tags: python, global-variables, counter

I came across this problem of not being able reference golbal variables from inside of a function. It always throws an error saying "local variable 'variable_name ' referenced before assignment".
I wrote a simple code which will throw the same error in trying to return a array of product of two numbers.

```
table=[]
counter = 0
def multiplier(num):

    if counter >9:
        print (table) 
    else:
        table.append(num*counter)
        counter +=1
        multiplier(num)

multiplier (5)
```

What am I doing wrong here? My original code requires the function to be called again and again for that I want to use a counter to keep track of how many times it is being called. This means I cannot initialize the counter inside of the function because once the function is called and because the counter is initialized inside the function, it will be reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `global` keyword at the first line in your function block.

Like:

```
def multiplier(num):
    global counter
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare

```
global counter
```

in your function to access the global variable instead of creating a local variable of the same name. The nicer solution would be to define a class, though.

Comment: There's no need to declare `table` as `global`. Because `table` is collection data type. Inside the function block, it just references the variable, not assigns new value.

Comment: You're right. Does it hurt, though (just not sure if it has any effect)?

Answer (score 1):

Make `counter` a parameter of the function with a default value of zero.  When you recurse, add one to the count.

```
table=[]
def multiplier(num, counter = 0):
    if counter >9:
        print (table) 
    else:
        table.append(num*counter)
        multiplier(num, counter+1)
multiplier(5)
```

---

Here is your function refactored to return a value instead of printing it.

```
table=[]
def multiplier(num, counter = 0):
    if counter >9:
        return table 
    else:
        table.append(num*counter)
        return multiplier(num, counter+1)
print(multiplier(5))
```

Comment: Hey, yes I was using this method up until I posted the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `global` keyword to use the global variable. Following points to keep in mind:

1. Use `global` keyword only when you are changing the global variable value.
2. You can use `global` variable if only reading just by using the variable name (global variable definition not required here).

Example:

```
var = 10

def change_var():
    global var
    var = 2
    return var

def read_var():
    print "Variable is:",var
```

Hope this helps.